# Why does my promise chain not run sequentially when I use an exported module, but it does when I don't export the module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback

I'm trying to get data as a csv from a URL in one file, and then convert that csv in another javascript file to a JSON object using a promise chain. The problem is, it's trying to convert the csv to json before the callback has actually retrieved the csv.
(Note: I realise I'm using the request library which is now deprecated, and will change it once I have the promise chain working).

File 1 (getting the csv data from the url) is below. I need to poll the url until it's populated with the data (usually takes about 5 mins - there are authentication steps beforehand, but they work fine so I'm omitting them to simplify this.) This returns a promise, which is exported as get_csv(). The promise resolves for a csv string.

```
const request = require('request');

const csv_url = foo;

module.exports.get_csv = () => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    function poll_url () {
      request.get({url: csv_url
      }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) console.error(error);
        data_csv = body;
        if (data_csv === ''){                             
          console.log("data_csv is blank.");
        } else {
          clearInterval(intervalID);
          console.log("data_csv has been populated!");
          resolve(data_csv);
        }
      })                        
    }                           

    pollURL()
    var intervalID = setInterval(poll_url, 60000);
  })                            
};
```

JS file 2 (changing the csv data to json) is below. It's meant to just add a .then() to the promise from file 1, which would transform the data from csv to json and then console.log() the json data.

```
const data = require('./get_csv_data');   // File 1
const csv = require('csvtojson');

new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  const data_csv_string = data.get_csv()
  resolve(data_csv_string);
})

.then(
  (data_csv_string) => {
    console.log(data_csv_string);                        // for debugging - giving undefined
    csv({output: "json"}).fromString(data_csv_string)    // "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"
    .then((data_json_string) => {
      console.log(data_json_string);
    })
  }
)
```

The problem is the .then() of file 2 doesn't wait for the first promise's callback to be completed. The console prints out:

```
undefined
(node:10691) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
data_csv is blank.
data_csv is blank.
data_csv is blank.
data_csv is blank.
data_csv is blank.
data_csv is blank.
data_csv has been populated!
```

What I can't wrap my head around is, if I put the .then() clause below at the end of File 1, it does work. What am I doing wrong?

```
.then(
  (data_csv_string) => {
    console.log(data_csv_string);                        
    csv({output: "json"}).fromString(data_csv_string)    
    .then((data_json_string) => {
      console.log(data_json_string);
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: You are not rejecting on errors, and you are not resolving if the string is empty.

Comment: If you must use request for now, use `request-promise`. Right now you are banging your head against the wall because you are forcing yourself to implement a promise from scratch. Use a library that returns a promise to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

File 2 needs to be:

```
const data = require('./get_csv_data');   // File 1
const csv = require('csvtojson');

data.get_csv().then(
  (data_csv_string) => {
    console.log(data_csv_string);                        // for debugging - giving undefined
    csv({output: "json"}).fromString(data_csv_string)    // "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"
    .then((data_json_string) => {
      console.log(data_json_string);
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This block

```
new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  const data_csv_string = data.get_csv()
  resolve(data_csv_string);
})
.then(
```

is wrong. If you want to wrap something (possibly a promise, possibly a value) within a promise, do

```
Promise.resolve(data.get_csv())
    .then(//...
```

But, as you know that `data.get_csv()` already returns a promise, there's no need for that. Just replace your Promise constructor with

```
data.get_csv()
    .then(//...
```

And by the way, there's a Node util for promisifying callback-based functions: `util.promisify`.

Comment: ah good point, I was returning a promise within a promise, though once I change it to your suggestion the only thing printed to the console is:
` TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined ` 
implying it still tries to perform the .then() before data.get_csv() is completed

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` should be avoided for use cases like this because in some circumstances, multiple invocations of the callback can be enqueued and then dequeued "rapid-fire". It is better to explicitly invoke the retry attempts when you know you are ready; this gives you more control.

There are a number of problems with your code.

For example:

```
pollURL()
var intervalID = setInterval(poll_url, 60000)
```

These lines kick-off the polling, even if the first attempt is successful, which might not be what you want.

Here is a refactoring (untested, obviously):

```js
const request = require('request')

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const repeatUntil = ({fn, condition, interval}) => {
    const go = async (...args) => {
        const result = await fn(...args)
        if(condition(result)) return result
        else {
            await delay(interval)
            await go(...args)
        }
    }
    return go
}

const getURL = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    request.get({url}, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) return reject(error)
        resolve({response, body})
    }))  

const csv_url = 'http://example.com'
const condition = ({body}) => !!body
const interval = 60000
const getCSV = repeatUntil({ fn: () => getURL(csv_url), condition, interval })

module.exports.getCSV = getCSV
```

**File 1**

```js
const getCSV = require('./get-csv')   // File 1
const csvToJSON = require('csvtojson')

getCSV()
    .then(({body}) => {
        const json = csvToJSON({output: "json"}).fromString(body) 
        console.log(json)
    })
```